# How to store this array result value in database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm getting this array result and I stored it in a variable. In this how can I store this into the database.

Server side language - PHP
Database             - phpmysql

I want to send the array result value to my Database to store the values. The values are from **["16",......,"1"]**

**Script I used**

```
$(".test_btn").click(function(){
     alert('submit-btn');
     var test1 = $(this).closest('tr').find(".evaluator-input").map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
     });
     console.log(test1);
});
```

**Array Result**

```
a.fn.init(17) ["16", "1", "Test", "test@gmail.com", "Test", "11", "22", "33", "44", "55", "66", "77", "88", "99", "00", "1", "1", selector: "", prevObject: a.fn.init(17), context: button.test_btn]
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty broad question. What server side language are you using, to process the request? What database are you using? How do you want to pass the data to the server?

Comment: I think this doesn't relate to PHP unless you have some presented PHP for us to analyze.

Answer (score 2):

First u need to send it to PHP, U can use AJAX for that, see example [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). After that u can send it to DB with `serialize` method, u can learn more about that [here](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.serialize.php)

Also u can send it like string from js code, already:

```
var test1 = $(this).closest('tr').find(".evaluator-input").map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
 });
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(test1);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

Now in PHP (script.php, or name of your file) u can use `var_dump($_POST['data']);` to see your data, then to send it to MySQL, u can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for this job, like that:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "yourdbname";
$dbusername = "yourusername";
$dbpassword = "yourpassword";

$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename(data)
    VALUES(:data)");
$statement->execute(array(
    "data" => $_POST['data'],
));
```

Of course u will have to change `INSERT query`, for your table and columns. In this case is good idea to use `key - value` columns, and after that to use `SELECT query` for key. Also it's really good idea to check before your query if  `$_POST['data'];` is already send and it's not empty.

Comment: can you share some demo or examples

Comment: what we do in **script.php**

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming you are using php as server side scripting language,
In order to store any array in database column store it as json_encoded string, use `json_encode` function to convert array to string and store it to database column

```
json_encode(["16", "1", "Test", "test@gmail.com", "Test", "11", "22", "33", "44", "55", "66", "77", "88", "99", "00", "1", "1"])
```

Whatever language you are using to store data in database, you can convert array to json and store as string in database or even store as a JSON dataype in table

Comment: Not sure if that is what they want to store, but at the moment it's a bit unclear what they want to do anyway.

Comment: Probably `JSON.stringify(some_array);` instead of `json_encode()` when sending data from browser to server.